# Methods with the same name and variables with same name in parent-child relation

Tags: java, object, inheritance, reference, parent-child

```java
class Super {
    public Integer i = 1;
    void Sample() {
        System.out.println("method of super class");
    }
}

public class Sub extends Super {
    public Integer i = 1000;
    void Sample() {
        System.out.println("method of sub class");
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Super obj;
        obj = new Super();
        obj.Sample();
        System.out.println(obj.i);
        obj = new Sub();
        obj.Sample();
        System.out.println(obj.i);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
method of superclass
1
method of subclass
1
```

When the `Sample()` method is called we get consequently different outputs (method of super class/subclass)

But when the variable, `i` is printed, outputs are identical (1)

Are problems the reference/object types or inheritance rules?

Answer (score 0):

Variables in Java do not follow polymorphism and overriding is only applicable to methods, not variables. Thus, you see the overriding behaviour for the method, `Sample()` but not for the variable, `i`.

Note that in this case, the child class variable hides the parent class variable and the concept is known as [variable hiding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3).

**Note:** Always follow the [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) e.g. you should rename the method, `Sample()` to `sample()`.